# Flutter: Is there any pacakage for audio analyzation?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, package, audio-analysis

Nowadays I need to develop an app, which can analyze an audio and extract its frequency and biterate. I have developed the function that choose a `mp3` or `m4a` audio and put it into the app. So is there any dart package can help me analyze the audio and extract frequency and biterate?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For flutter current this kind of advanced featured package is not much available.

I found a package for getting bitrate, sample rate, CRC check, duration etc. from a mp3 file. You can check and try it out. [MP3 Info](https://pub.dev/packages/mp3_info)

Otherwise you have to write code on android, ios and other platforms code for extracting bitrate and frequency and bridge those code to dart/flutter so that you can call those code from your flutter application.

Comment: do you know something about _how to write code on android, ios and other platforms code for extracting bitrate and frequency_?